# Background Images - Overlay on top

Tags: modeling, interface, image, customization

Is it possible to have a "background image" be an overlay with opacity control instead of being behind the mesh?

The default background image: (as the name suggests)
[image]

How I would like it:
[image]

Comment: [Backround images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html#settings) have Back and Front options to draw themselves over or under everything, with Front it will kind of look like in your 2nd image.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that option... sigh.
Thanks, this is perfect!!

Comment: @MrZak please write an answer, let's get this question out the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Answered by @MrZak"
There is a **Back** and **Front** option under the Background Images options.

[image]